# Xcode: How to clean all projects, rather than just 1 project?

Tags: xcode

I have an Xcode solution with 5 projects present.  ("Solution" is the Visual Studio term for the overall running IDE instance's main area with all of its projects; I am not sure what the Xcode equivalent term is.)

I would like to perform a clean/rebuild on all 5 projects.

Unfortunately, when I select Product -> Clean, Xcode **only cleans one of the 5 projects**.  You can see this in the second screenshot below.

The project that Xcode chooses to clean (out of the 5) is an executable (application).  Of the remaining 4 projects that I'd like Xcode to clean as well, 1 is a dynamic library, and 3 are static libraries.

How, using Xcode, am I able to clean *every* project in the solution, rather than just 1 project?

Here are screenshots of my setup.

(1) Screenshot of the Xcode main screen, showing my 5 projects listed in the left pane.

[image: Xcode5projects]

(2) Screenshot of the log, showing my attempt to clean all the projects in the solution via Project -> Clean.  The top (most recent) entry is selected in the left pane.  In the main pane, you can see that only 1 out of the 5 projects in the solution has actually been cleaned by Xcode.

[image: XcodeOnlyCleans1Project]

Thanks!

**ADDENDUM**

In response to Martin's answer.  I have held the Option key while selecting the Project menu, and I do not see a "clean build folder" option.  See screenshot.

(3) Screenshot of the Project menu showing, when the Project menu was selected with the Option key held down.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you hold the option-key while selecting the "Product" menu, you can choose
"Clean Build Folder ...". This should delete all generated files from all projects in your workspace.

Comment: Thanks, Martin.  I have pressed the Option key while selecting the Project menu, and I do not see a "Clean Build Folder..." option.  I have addended my question to attach a screenshot of the Project menu when selected with the Option key held down.  Might the lack of the "Clean Build Folder..." option be due to the fact that there is not a single build folder?  For this Xcode solution, I have simply added 5 separate projects in different folders, one at a time.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: Strange. The direct shortcut (in my configuration) is Option+Shift+Command+K, does that work?

Comment: Note: I am running OSX in a virtual machine.  Generally, I use the Windows key as the Command key, and it works.  I will attempt this and let you know.

Comment: I have discovered that this is a virtual machine keystroke issue.  My apologies.  In the virtual machine, the Alt key (on the Windows keyboard) is the Option key.  I did not realize that.  If you are willing to followup, I have a related question: Although the text "Clean Finished" appears when I select "Clean Build Folder...", I do not see an entry in the Log Navigator list.  Does this this seem correct?

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: Yes, same here. "Clean Build Folder ..." just deletes the entire "DerivedData" folder and does not appear in the Log Navigator.

Answer (score 1):

You can clean the build folder by pressing Command+Option+Shift+K. Also, for Martin R's answer, open the Product folder and then press Option. I believe that you have to continue holding option to see the Clean Build Folder option.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I said in my answer and the comments?

Comment: Yeah, I started the response before your Command+Option+Shift+K comment was posted. Dan, please give Martin credit for the answer.